# Using fstab File When Mounting Filesystem

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I installed Arch Linux using BTRFS, but I was having issues with wifi. I have to mount the drive from the Live CD. But, when I mount using:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/arch
```

It doesn't use the fstab file from `/dev/sda1`. This is causing issues. In the `fstab` file I am binding `/var/lib` to `/run/btrfs-root/ROOT/var/lib`. Because of this I am unable to use `pacman` because it's not binding when mounted.

How can I mount the drive and have it use the `fstab` file to bind and mount the subvolumes?

Comment: Enter chroot, `mount -a`?

Comment: @mid_kid does that use the `fstab` file within the filesystem I'm trying to mount though?

Comment: @mid_kid Yes, you should post this as an answer.